# COPY --from=build /path/to/dist /usr/share/nginx/html not working

Tags: angular, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a dockerfile for an Angular app:

```
# Stage 1: Build the Angular application
FROM node:21 as build
WORKDIR /studio-frontend
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# Stage 2: Serve the application from Nginx
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=build /studio-frontend/dist/studio-frontend/browser /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

../docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  postgres:
    ...
  pgadmin:
    ...
  api:
    build: .
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=...
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"  # Web server port
      - "9229:9229" # Used for debug mode
    depends_on:
      - postgres
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./studio-frontend
    ports:
      - "8080:80"

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

When I run `docker compose build --no-cache` everything builds and completes successfully (no errors). But when I view the application at http://localhost:3000 the changes aren't reflected that I've made to my Angular application. If however, I manually run `npm run build` for the Angular application, then run `docker compose up -d` I DO SEE the changes reflected.

I can see that the actual path to the complied Angular code (relative to docker-compose.yml) is `/studio-frontend/dist/studio-frontend/browser` (here I see index.html long with chunk{ID}.js, main{ID}.js, etc.)

It APPEARS that the value `/studio-frontend/dist/studio-frontend/browser` from the `COPY --from=build` command is accurate. If I omit the first `/studio-frontend` I get an error:

```
 [frontend stage-1 2/2] COPY --from=build /dist/studio-frontend/browser /usr/share/nginx/html:
------
failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref a2e51685-f0b2-477c-a59a-4ccc6c2150d2::uzo7yihyok9xsdxni7xy7kzpe: failed to walk /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount2325902515/dist/studio-frontend: lstat /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount2325902515/dist/studio-frontend: no such file or directory
```

But I'm not sure what I'm missing.